# Tutorial for Windows Worflow Foundation (WF)

Tags: database, workflow-foundation

I just need videos or tutorial to teach me how can I pass parameters ( values or objects ) from DB to workflow and from my workflow to DB

I mean, when a value changes during the running of workflow how i can update it in DB? 
I really need help, i very new in WF

Answer (score 2):

We have some great resources for you in this blog post [Want to Learn Windows Workflow Fondation?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/10/13/want-to-learn-windows-workflow-4-wf4.aspx) In particular, the [Contoso HR Sample Application](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Server-AppFabric-e2eb68f5) includes activities that read/write database using Entity Framework.